# How to fix "Run-time error '424 Object required error

Tags: excel, vba, variables

So, to summarize this as much as possible, i'm trying to create a document that calculates one or more fiscal weeks at a time using an user form (based on my team's daily activity). The issue here is that i get a runtime error once i select the week and confirm my selection once the user form is displayed.
If needed, i can also provide the excel document.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
coloana_has_been_done = "P"
test_verificare_1 = 0
test_verificare_2 = 0   
saptamana_selectata = GRPweek.ListBox1.Value   
If IsEmpty(saptamana_selectata) Or saptamana_selectata = "" Or GRPweek.ListBox1.ListIndex = -1 Then
    MsgBox "No GRP week has been selected !", vbCritical, "Error"
    Exit Sub
Else
    test_verificare_1 = 1
End If      
Dim db_page As Worksheet
Set db_page = Sheets("baza_date")

rand_data = data_cautata.Row

Set data_cautata = db_page.Columns("O:O").Find(What:=saptamana_selectata, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
If Range(coloana_has_been_done & rand_data).Value = 1 Then
    MsgBox "The selected GRP week is already Completed", vbCritical, "Error"
    Exit Sub
Else
    test_verificare_2 = 1
End If
If test_verificare_1 = 1 And test_verificare_2 = 1 Then
    Call grp(rand_data)
    Unload Me
End If
End Sub
```

The line that holds the runtime '424' issue is:

```
rand_data = data_cautata.Row
```

Comment: At the time the command line `rand_data = data_cautata.Row` occurs, the `data_cautata` is nothing. Only after it will be `Set` to something.

Comment: Ah, yes you are right. I've put the line after the **set data_cautata =** instruction, and now i get runtime error '91' object or with block not set

Comment: Then `db_page.Columns("O:O").Find` does not find something so the result `data_cautata` is `Nothing` again.

Comment: I would recommend reading something about how to [Debugging VBA](https://bettersolutions.com/vba/debugging/index.htm).

Comment: I found out that **rand_data = nothing**, but i can't understand why because i can't seem to find any errors within the code. More over, every other variable that is listed until that line, gets the required value as intended....